# What is "the key" in my Google Sheets URL?

Tags: google-sheets

I have found many posts from awhile ago that talk about the `key` in the URL. Problem is when I am trying to input the key, there is none. Well at least I cannot determine what the key is.

This is the URL I get;

> https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11jp7-1POyw_cunE1imQ80Bqxj8U93a4hvHmKpWLY5K8/edit#gid=0.

As you can see, there is no key= so I am at a lost.  I have tried trial and error with no success.

Comment: This is your key: `11jp7-1POyw_cunE1imQ80Bqxj8U93a4hvHmKpWLY5K8`

Comment: And if you're using the new Google Spreadsheets, you use the entire link.

Comment: @Punchlinern In combination with `IMPORTRANGE()`?

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra Yes, from [docs for IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en): _In the new Google Sheets, use the entire URL._

Answer (score 3):

This is your key:

> 11jp7-1POyw_cunE1imQ80Bqxj8U93a4hvHmKpWLY5K8

As @Punchlinern mentioned in his comments, with the new Google Sheets you can use the entire URL in combination with the `IMPORTRANGE()` formula. Using the above-mentioned key, the old style, works as well.

[image]

Reference: [IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en)