# Can I call IMPORTRANGE function inside a REGEXEXTRACT function?

Tags: google-sheets, importrange, regexextract

I want to obtain root domains from a list of URLs with REGEXEXTRACT but want the list of all possible TLDs to come from another sheet, to avoid specifying `com|net|org|all other` by hand. Basic idea:

```
  =REGEXEXTRACT(A2, "\w+\.(?:com|net|org)")
```

What I want:

```
  =REGEXEXTRACT(A2, "\w+\.(?:IMPORTRANGE("$SHEETKEY",!A2:A))")
```

Any way to achieve this?

Comment: This `REGEX` is limited to the sub domain `www`. Should it cover more than that?

Comment: It extracts root domain (domain.com) from full URL.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this.

### Formula

*new Google Sheet*

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTRANGE("URL_IMPORT_SHEET", "A2"), "(\w+\.\w+)$")
```

*old Google Spreadsheet*

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTRANGE("KEY_IMPORT_SHEET", "A2"), "(\w+\.\w+)$")
```

For a range you need to do this.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTRANGE("URL_OR_KEY", "A2:A14"), "(\w+\.\w+)$"))
```

### References

- URL or KEY: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/74206/29140
- REGEX: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21173813/1536038

Comment: No,  i want to get list of all TLDs from other sheet and use that instead of specifying them in com|net|org fashion.

Comment: @purpler Would that yield the same result?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out. Logic said it would but i failed to get it working, probably due to lack of understanding of Sheets formula syntax.

Comment: @purpler Perhaps based on your locale, try this: `=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTRANGE("URL_OR_KEY"; "A2:A14"); "\w+\.(?:com|net|org)"))`

Comment: You dont seem to understand what I'm trying to achieve. I want to import all possible TLDs (instead of just com,  net,  org) from other sheet or document and use them for regex.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing that `A2` contains something like `https://webapps.stackexchange.com` and that another sheet contains something like: A2 `com`, A3 `net`, A4 `org` then in say B1:

```
=TEXTJOIN("|",1,IMPORTRANGE(" k e y ","A2:A"))
```

should return something like `com|net|org` provided permission is granted.

This may be applied within a REGEXEXTRACT formula like so:

```
 =REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"\w+\.(?:"&B$1&")")
```

to return, for the example: `stackexchange.com` (a link to `https://stackexchange.com/`) and for `https://www.draw.io/` return `#N/A`.

[TEXTJOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992)
[IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340)
[REGEXEXTRACT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244)